# Send iOS app crash report to server from Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, crash-reports

I want to send crash report to server, from any `view controller`. 
I tried `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` but it is implemented in `delegate`.
As I am creating `library`, so I want to send crash report from `library`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use frameworks available

- Crashlytics
- Instabug
- HockeyApp
- Parse

Answer (score 1):

Your "library" can be a class, which you can instantiate (e.g. as a singleton), or call class methods. Include the header file, and you can call it from anywhere.

If you instantiate it globally (e.g. as a singleton), then you can also have it handle delegate methods, such as those from `NSURLSession`.

You can even create your own protocol and delegate methods to bubble up events to the caller.